# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 200:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.1

I have these route declaration here

```
//Skill
Route::get('skill','SkillController@index');
Route::get('skill/create','SkillController@create');
Route::post('skill/store','SkillController@store');
Route::get('skill/{id}','SkillController@show');
Route::get('skill/{id}/edit', 'SkillController@edit');
Route::post('skill/{id}/update','SkillController@update');
Route::delete('skill/{id}/destroy','SkillController@destroy');
```

With these routes, I can delete fine on local.

When I tried to delete on production, I kept getting

[image]

I know for sure, I had this line

> Route::delete('skill/{id}/destroy','SkillController@destroy');

- Local and Prod have the same codebase.
- Local = Mac OS X
- Prod = Ubuntu Server

What did I missed ?

Comment: Are you actually sending a DELETE http request? How did you arrive at this screenshot?

Comment: Check your access logs to see what type of request is actually hitting the server.

Comment: I'll db check my form as HTML code. Good hints :D !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route is triggered from a form... Yes? Your form method should be `POST`, not `DELETE` and then you should add a hidden input to make it work as `DELETE` route, thus helping you maintain `Route::delete()`. 
Your form should look like this:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

And your route:

```
Route::delete('skill/{id}/destroy','SkillController@destroy');
```

Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing for more insight.

Comment: I am on 5.1 - please check your answer.

Comment: Not a problem... Method spoofing is supported in 5.1... Simply go to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 3):

As your problem is on production only which is linux server I think it may be .htaccess issue.

Often web servers will be configured to block anything except GET and POST since 99% of the time they're all that are needed and there have been problems in the past with applications assuming the requests were one of those two.

You could try an .htaccess with

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
 Allow from all
</Limit>
```

(I'm not an expert at apache, this may not be exactly correct)

Comment: Okay, let me try that.

Comment: Yeah. let me know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote down your request in browser address bar it supposed to be GET or POST. That's why you got the mistake.

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException: It means that the route is correct, but method is mistaken. You used POST method  - this method is automatic if you use browser. But you need DELETE method.

In order to use DELETE method you should use API client. 
PhpStorm has API built-in API client. [PHPStorm RESTApi client docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/rest-client-tool-window.html)
[image]

But! For me the best way is to use **Postman**! [Postman sending requests docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests)